# Linux Ubuntu 12.04 Fortran77 OpenMP seg fault with ulimit -s unlimited

Tags: segmentation-fault, openmp, blas, fortran77

I'm having a seg fault issue with a F77 script (to be given below) which employs OpenMP, when I increase the the index of a loop past a certain threshold. I realize this is a common issue, but I have found a work around on a mac, and am trying to figure out how to do the same thing on my linux machine.

The code is included below, and I apologize for its length - the majority of the script is devoted to setting up matrices to be multiplied via ZGEMM. Note, as I increase the number of equations, denoted by neq in my code, I get the aforementioned seg fault issues.

```
  program test2

  implicit none
  include 'omp_lib.h'
  integer neq, niv, Mt
  parameter (neq = 4*200)
  parameter (niv = neq/4)
  double precision y(neq), yp(neq), atol(neq), u(niv)
  integer m, j, kk, l, n, l1, l2, l3, i, ll, indsum, indsum2
  integer indsum3, i4, k, k1, k2,k3, k4, k5, k6, l2p, l2pp
  integer k3a, k3b
  double complex p(-niv:niv,-niv:niv), V(niv), resd2a,
 &  Vec(-niv:niv), p2(1:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex qmat(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex qmat2(1:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat0(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)      
  double complex sqmat1(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat2(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat3(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv),
 &  C(-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex sqmat3b(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv),
 &  sqmat3c(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv) 
  double complex q(-niv:niv,-niv:niv), q2(-niv:niv,-niv:niv),
 & smat(-niv:niv,-niv:niv,-niv:niv), alpha, beta
  double complex sumdum, sum1, sum2(niv), sum3(niv), qsum,
 &  resd, resd2, sumdum2, out(-niv:niv,-niv:niv)
  double complex ssum1, ssum2, forcing(niv)
  double precision seconds


  call omp_set_num_threads ( 16 )
  seconds = omp_get_wtime ( )


  write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
  write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) 
 &  '  Number of processors available = ', omp_get_num_procs ( )
  write ( * ,'(a,i8)' ) 
 &  '  Number of threads =              ', omp_get_max_threads ( )
  y = 0
  do i = 1, niv
  y(i) = 0.1d0*i
  enddo
  do i = niv+1,2*niv
  y(i) = 0.2d0
  enddo


  do  j = -niv, niv
      do m = -niv, niv
      kk = m-j
      l = m-j
      k1 = m
      k2 = j
      k3a = m
      k3b = j
      k4 = m-j
      k5 = j
      k6 = m-j
      if (abs(kk) .gt. niv) then
      kk = 0
      else 
      kk = 1
      end if
      if (k1 .eq. 0) then
      k1 = 0
      else
      k1=1
      end if
      if (k2.eq.0) then
      k2 = 0
      else
      k2 = 1
      end if
      if (k3a .eq. 0) then
      k3a=1
      else 
      k3a=0
      end if
      if (k3b .eq. 0) then
      k3b=1
      else 
      k3b=0
      end if
      if (k4 .eq. 0) then
      k4 = 0
      else
      k4 = 1
      end if
      if (k5 .eq. 0) then
      k5=2
      else
      k5=1
      end if
      if (k6 .eq. 0) then
      k6=2
      else
      k6=1
      end if
  p(m,j)=(0.5*k5*k6*kk*abs(k4*sign(1,m-j)-k2*sign(1,j))*cmplx(k4
 & *y(abs(m-j))+1-k4,k4*y(niv+abs(m-j))*sign(1,m-j))-0.5*cmplx(k1*
 & y(abs(m))+(1-k1), k1*y(abs(m)+niv)*sign(1, m))*cmplx(k2*y(abs(j
 & ))+(1-k2),-k2*y(abs(j)+niv)*sign(1,j)))/((abs(m)+k3a)**(0.5)*(
 & k3b+abs(j)))
   enddo  
  enddo 


  Mt= 2*niv+1
  alpha = cmplx(0.25d0,0.0d0)
  beta = cmplx(0.0d0,0.0d0)

  call ZGEMM('T','N',Mt,Mt,niv,alpha, p(1:niv,-niv:niv),niv,
 &p(-1:-niv:-1,-niv:niv),niv,beta, q ,Mt)



  do m= -niv, niv
  do j= -niv, niv
  do n= -niv, niv
  kk = m-j
  k1 = m
  k2 = j
  k3a = m
  k3b = j
  k5 = m-j 
  k6 = j
  l = m-j
   if (abs(kk). gt. niv) then 
    kk = 0
   else
    kk = 1
   end if
   indsum = m-j-n
   if (indsum .eq. 0) then
   indsum = 1
   else
   indsum = 0
   end if
   indsum2 = m+j-n
   if (indsum2 .eq. 0) then
   indsum2 = 1
   else
   indsum2 = 0
   end if
   indsum3 = j+n
   if (indsum3 .eq. 0) then
   indsum3 = 1
   else
   indsum3 = 0
   end if
   i4 = m-n
   if (i4 .eq. 0) then
   i4 = 1
   else
   i4 = 0
   end if 
   if (k3a .eq. 0) then
   k3a=1
   else 
   k3a=0
   end if
   if (k3b .eq. 0) then
   k3b=1
   else 
   k3b=0
   end if
   if (k1 .eq. 0) then
   k1 = 0
   else
   k1 = 1
   end if
   if (k2 .eq. 0) then
   k2 = 0
   else
   k2 = 1
   end if
      if (k5 .eq. 0) then
      k5=2
      else
      k5=1
      end if
      if (k6 .eq. 0) then
      k6=2
      else
      k6=1
      end if
      if (l.eq.0) then
      l = 0
      else
      l = 1
      end if
   qmat(m,j,n) = (0.5*k5*k6*kk*abs(l*sign(1,m-j)-k2*sign(1,j))*
 &    cmplx(indsum,0)-0.5*indsum3*cmplx(y(abs(m))+1-k1,sign(1,
 &    m)*y(abs(m)+niv))-0.5*i4*cmplx(y(abs(j))+1-k2, -sign(1,
 &    j)*y(abs(j)+niv)))/((abs(m)+k3a)**(0.5)*(
 &    k3b+abs(j)))
  enddo 
  enddo 
  enddo 





  c$omp parallel private(n) shared(sqmat3)
  c$omp do 

  do n=-niv  ,niv  
  call ZGEMM('T','N',Mt,Mt,niv,alpha, qmat(1:niv,-niv:niv,n),niv,
 &p(-1:-niv:-1,-niv:niv),niv,beta, sqmat0(:,:,n),Mt)
  call ZGEMM('T','N',Mt,Mt,niv,alpha,p(1:niv,-niv:niv)
 & ,niv,qmat(-1:-niv:-1,-niv:niv,n),niv,beta, sqmat2(:,:,n),Mt)
   sqmat3(:,:,n) = sqmat0(:,:,n)+sqmat2(:,:,n)
  enddo

  c$omp end do 
  c$omp end parallel

  seconds = omp_get_wtime ( ) - seconds;
  print*, seconds

  return
  end
```

The seg fault is due to the last loop, involving the loop over matrix multiplications.

Now, I compile this on my mac using:

```
  $gfortran -fopenmp -O3 -Wl,-stack_size,0x320000000 test.f -lblas
```

and I find that the program executes and gives me the expected result. Note, if I set the stacksize to, for instance,

```
  -stack_size,0x80000000
```

I get a seg fault.

On my linux machine (Ubunut 12.04 _x86_64) I have set

```
  ulimit -s unlimited
```

and compile with

```
  $gfortran -fopenmp -O3 test2.f /home/user/OpenBLAS/libopenblas.a
```

and I get a segmentation fault. Checking ulimit -a, I see the stacksize is set to unlimited. Also, I have played around with setting the stacksizes of the slave threads using, for instance,

```
 $export OMP_STACKSIZE=16M
```

but this does not seem to help. It seems to me that, based on a similar issue on my mac, I must increase the stacksize to something over 8M, but can't seem to force the linux machine to do this.

So, my question is, what is the easiest way to overcome an issue like this? I am certainly a beginner, so any recommendations are appreciated.

Nick

Comment: why limiting yourself to 16M? you're dealing with matrices that are 1GB big (if they are 400**3 big), i would just try increasing the openmp stack to gb size...

Comment: @Spock I guess my question is how to do this on Ubuntu? Setting ulimit -s unlimited is not sufficient...